I am getting an error when install the drizzle-orm npm package in my nextjs 14 app
npm i drizzle-orm postgres
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: full-stack-todo@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@14.2.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/next
npm ERR!       next@"14.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (styled-jsx, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! drizzle-orm@"" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"" from @op-engineering/op-sqlite@5.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@op-engineering/op-sqlite
npm ERR!       peerOptional @op-engineering/op-sqlite@">=2" from drizzle-orm@0.30.9
npm ERR!       node_modules/drizzle-orm
npm ERR!         drizzle-orm@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Aimable\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-01T06_29_32_052Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Aimable\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-01T06_29_32_052Z-debug-0.log
I was expecting it to be installed but I got the error

I solved updating all the dependences running
npm update --save
npm update --save-dev

then
npm install --save drizzle-orm

That will update the package.json with
  "dependencies": {
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.30.10",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.20.17",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }


Why?...........

Why not! :)
It is clear that the current version of drizzle-orm is not compatible with the package.json generated by npx create-next-app@latest. Specifically it doesn't like the 18.0.0 React version.

Could be an issue with Drizzle running behind a version. Try adding/changing the following in package.json and doing an npm i
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.30.9",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"

It's likely you have "react": "^18" in the package.json right now.

This helped me, I used these steps to set react version to 18.2.0, as indicated in the error message, then did an npm i and it worked. Thank you!

Even I came across this problem while installing drizzle-orm into the next.js project.
This is the workflow that helped me out of this problem.
1. Update Dependencies:

Run the following command in your terminal to update all existing dependencies listed in your package.json file to their latest compatible versions and save the changes back to the file:
npm update --save


This command ensures your project uses the most recent stable versions of its dependencies, potentially improving security and functionality.


2. Update Development Dependencies:

Next, update all development dependencies (packages used for building, testing, or linting but not included in the final production build) with the following command:
npm update --save-dev


Similar to the previous step, this keeps your development environment up-to-date with the latest tools.


3. Install Drizzle ORM:

Finally, install the drizzle-orm package as a dependency by running:
npm install --save drizzle-orm


This command adds drizzle-orm to your project's dependencies and downloads the necessary files.


I hope this helps!

I'm using Next.js 15 and was getting similar issue.

Error please install required packages: 'drizzle-orm'

after running pnpm update I got ( which is absurd... )

Please install latest version of drizzle-orm

The workaround I found was pnpm exec drizzle-kit generate
Source: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/2699#issuecomment-2322825749
